# DAX - Running total based on date filtering where same daily total is on multiple rows due to multiple outputs for same day

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, cumulative-sum

I am trying to use DAX in Power BI and no matter how I try, I cannot seem to get this right.

My source data comprises of the output of a stored procedure in SQL that calculates the pass and fail rate of several validation checks against a set of raw data that also changes in row size daily. As such, my data for each day has the same number of validation check types and gives the total number of rows checked for each one as the same value - for example:

Table

| Date | Check Ref. | Rows Passed | Rows Failed | Total Rows Checked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/21 | Check 1 | 20 | 200 | 220 |
| 01/01/21 | Check 2 | 40 | 180 | 220 |
| 01/01/21 | Check 3 | 60 | 160 | 220 |
| 01/01/21 | Check 4 | 10 | 210 | 220 |
| 01/01/21 | Check 5 | 15 | 205 | 220 |
| 02/01/21 | Check 1 | 20 | 230 | 250 |
| 02/01/21 | Check 2 | 200 | 50 | 250 |
| 02/01/21 | Check 3 | 100 | 150 | 250 |
| 02/01/21 | Check 4 | 40 | 210 | 250 |
| 02/01/21 | Check 5 | 160 | 90 | 250 |
| 03/01/21 | Check 1 | 290 | 10 | 300 |
| 03/01/21 | Check 2 | 110 | 190 | 300 |
| 03/01/21 | Check 3 | 25 | 275 | 300 |
| 03/01/21 | Check 4 | 175 | 125 | 300 |
| 03/01/21 | Check 5 | 20 | 280 | 300 |

etc. etc.

I want to be able to show in the report tab a KPI card that shows the number of rows checked on any particular day (e.g. 220 on 01/01/21) and a cumulative (running) total of any dates I select (e.g. if I selected 02/01/21 and 03/01/21, I would expect to see 550)

I have tried to create a quick measure to divide the sum of total rows checked by the count of the date (which I am thinking should equal 5) - this works for single dates - but when I select multiple dates in a filter, I just get an average of the values. The same occurs when I try and do a running count by date and average sum of total rows checked.

The only way I have been able to get it to work is by giving each of the validation checks an index from 1 to 5 and then creating two quick measures, firstly to give me the value of the number of rows checked on any given day and then creating a running total measure filtering on date and the earlier dimension measure created:

```
Dimension Measure = 
        Calculate(
          SUM('Table'[Total Rows Checked]),
          'Table'[Check Ref. Index]
             in { 1 }

(where 1 refers to index 1 (check 1))

Running Total Measure = 
     Calculate (
         [Dimension Measure],
         FILTER(
            ALLSELECTED('Table'[Date]),
            ISONORAFTER('Table'[Date], MAX('Table'[Date]), DESC)
         )
)
```

Surely this is a ridiculous way of doing it and that there is a better way?

Apologies for any faux pas with my question or its formatting - it's my first ever question!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about taking the sum of the max [Total Rows Checked] for each date within your selection?

```
Rows Checked =
SUMX (
    VALUES ( 'Table'[Date] ),
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[Total Rows Checked] ) )
)
```

Alternatively, you could take the first check from each day like this:

```
Rows Checked =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[Total Rows Checked] ),
    'Table'[Check Ref.] = "Check 1"
)
```

Comment: Hi @Alexis Olson - Thank you so much - you are my hero! This is massively helpful and makes sense now. My issue has been that I am pretty new to DAX and so not too comfortable with the syntax yet, so using quick measures to feel my way around things!